# I need my appbar to show on different dart files I'm creating in android studio

Tags: flutter, appbar, bottom-navigation-bar

Need your assistance.

I'm working on a flutter project using android studio. I'm finding it hard to display the Appbar when the bottom navigation bar is there. When I have them both, the appbar doesn't show when I run the app but when I remove the bottomnavbar, the Appbar becomes visible. How can I resolve this? This happens to all new dart files I create that I want to include an appbar.

I created a widget for the bottomnavbar on a different dart file. See code below: PS, Adding an appbar to this code below works well but not the other files where I vave a different appbar and calling the bottomnavbar like this: bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:salomon_bottom_bar/salomon_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:tikosocial/constants.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomNavBar> createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  var currentIndex=0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.15),
                blurRadius: 30,
                offset: const Offset(0, 10),
              ),
            ],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          child: SalomonBottomBar(
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            onTap: (i) => setState(() => currentIndex = i),
            items: [
              /// Home
              SalomonBottomBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.home_max_outlined),
                title: const Text("Home"),
                selectedColor: kHomeColor,
              ),

              /// Ticket
              SalomonBottomBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.local_activity_outlined),
                title: const Text("Ticket"),
                selectedColor: kPrimaryColor,
              ),

              /// Search
              SalomonBottomBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                title: const Text("Search"),
                selectedColor: kPrimaryColor,
              ),

              /// Profile
              SalomonBottomBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
                title: const Text("Account"),
                selectedColor: kHomeColor,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

But when I call it on a separate file only the bottomnavbar shows. See code sample below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tikosocial/bottom_nav.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: const Row(

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: kindly add your code so that we can have a look at possible issue.

Comment: I have added an answer, please let me know if worked, otherwise add more content or examples to this question.

Comment: You shouldnt use a Scaffold widget inside your BottomNavBar class, just return SalomonBottomBar. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

To use AppBar + BottomNavigationBar follow this steps:

In your base file `main.dart`:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      home: const MyPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

In the file of your first page, in this case `MyPage()` class:

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  int index = 0;

  updateIndex(int i) {
    setState(() => index = i);
  }

  List<Widget> contentList = [
    const Center(child: Text('Page 1')),
    const Center(child: Text('Page 2')),
    const Center(child: Text('Page 3')),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('AppBar Title'),
      ),
      body: contentList[index],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: updateIndex,
        currentIndex: index,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
            label: 'A',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: 'B',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            label: 'C',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This way your `AppBar` will be static and your page content will be updated according to the tapped index of the `BottomNavigationBar`.

In case you want to add content from different files, you should call your widget inside `contentList`. Make sure not to create another scaffold because you already have one in this page.

In case you want to make your `AppBar` dynamic (different content for indexes tapped), you could assign your `BottomNavigationBar` index and build different appbars, doing the same as in `contentList`.

Comment: Hello Johan. I appreciate your feedback. Check my code above and advice...